# Magento getCollection() in Grid returns false

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm currently in the process of learning how to work with the Magento backend. I have created a model class `example/event` and a corresponding resource. I am able to add records (via a Magento admin form) to a DB table I have created `example_event`. I am having trouble however retrieving records from my table. My Gird class is as follows:

```
class MasteringMagento_Example_Block_Adminhtml_Event_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid {

    protected function _prepareCollection() {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('example/event')->getCollection();
        var_dump($collection); // bool(false)

        //$record = Mage::getModel('example/event')->load(1); //id from example_event table
        //var_dump($record); // returns object record as expected

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns() {
        $this->addColumn('name', array(
               'type'=>'text',
               'index'=>'name',
               'header'=>$this->__('Name')
        ));

        $this->addColumn('start', array(
               'type'=>'date',
               'index'=>'start',
               'header'=>$this->__('Start Date')
        ));

        $this->addColumn('end', array(
               'type'=> 'date',
               'index'=>'end',
               'header'=>$this->__('End Date')
        ));

        return $this;
    }

}
```

As noted in the code, `$collection = Mage::getModel('example/event')->getCollection()` returns false. However I am able to retrieve a single record from my database table by using `$record = Mage::getModel('example/event')->load(1);` where 1 is the ID of the record (this is simply a sanity check to ensure that at least something I wrote can talk to the DB). The goal is to render the collection to the grid built by the `_prepareColumns()` function.

Again, I am brand new to programming in the Magento backend, but I have been through my code over and over and cannot seem to figure out why my collection object is empty.

Comment: So, you can load(1), but you cannot load all collection?

Comment: First, check the `var/log` folder for errors. Then, make sure that this file exists: `MasteringMagento/Example/Model/Resource/Event/Collection.php`. If it does, then post the contents of that file and the contents of config.xml and `MasteringMagento/Example/Model/Event.php` in your question.

Comment: @sergio that is correct.

Comment: @Marius I have `MasteringMagento/Example/Model/Resource/Event.php`. I am missing `MasteringMagento/Example/Model/Resource/Event/Collection.php`. The guide I am following did not make any mention of such a class, so perhaps that is the issue. I will look further into that. As I said, I'm brand new to it, so thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can:

```
$record = Mage::getModel('example/event')->load(1)
```

But you can not

```
Mage::getModel('example/event')->getCollection();
```

The main reason of this that you `did not creat collection model in your module`. 
Need to do something like this:

```
class MasteringMagento_Example_Model_Resource_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract {    
    protected function _construct() {
       $this->_init('example/event');
    }    
}
```

Comment: and @marius Thank you, thank you! That was it. I needed `class MasteringMagento_Example_Model_Resource_Event_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` in `MasteringMagento/Example/Model/Resource/Event/Collection.php`. I am understanding more now how to work with models in Magento. Surprisingly the tutorial I am working with makes no mention of the Collection Abstract. Might need a new tutorial.